# How to refactor componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate or possibly a Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this application that has a deprecated lifecycle method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }
```

Currently, I have used the `UNSAFE_` flag:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }
```

I have left it like this because when I attempted to refactor it to:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if (this.state.displayErrors) {
       this._validate(prevProps, prevState);
     }
   }
```

It created another bug that gave me this error:

> Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen
>   when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate
>   or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

It starts to happen when a user clicks on the PAY NOW button that kicks off the `_handlePayButtonPress` which also checks for validation of credit card information like so:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }

  _validate = props => {
    const { cardExpireDate, cardNumber, csv, nameOnCard } = props;

    const validationErrors = {
      date: cardExpireDate.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      cardNumber: cardNumber.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      csv: csv.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      name: nameOnCard.trim() ? "" : "Is Required"
    };

    if (validationErrors.csv === "" && csv.trim().length < 3) {
      validationErrors.csv = "Must be 3 or 4 digits";
    }

    const fullErrors = {
      ...validationErrors,
      ...this.props.validationErrors
    };
    const isValid = Object.keys(fullErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (fullErrors[curr]) {
        return false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, true);

    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ validationErrors: {} });
      //register
    } else {
      this.setState({ validationErrors, displayErrors: true });
    }

    return isValid;
  };

  _handlePayButtonPress = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate(this.props);

    if (isValid) {
      console.log("Good to go!");
    }

    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ processingPayment: true });
      this.props
        .submitEventRegistration()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ processingPayment: false });
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          this.props.navigation.navigate("PaymentConfirmation");
        })
        .catch(({ title, message }) => {
          Alert.alert(
            title,
            message,
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => {
                  this.setState({ processingPayment: false });
                }
              }
            ],
            {
              cancelable: false
            }
          );
        });
    } else {
      alert("Please correct the errors before continuing.");
    }
  };
```

Unfortunately, I do not have enough experience with Hooks and I have failed at refactoring that deprecated lifecycle method to one that would not create trouble like it was doing with the above error. Any suggestions at a better CDU or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another check so you don't get in an infinite loop (every time you call setState you will rerender -> component did update -> update again ...)

You could do something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if (this.state.displayErrors && prevProps !== this.props) {
       this._validate(prevProps, prevState);
     }
   }
```

Also I think that you need to call your validate with new props and state:

```
this._validate(this.props, this.state);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am actually still getting an infinite loop if I click on PAY NOW without adding credit card info. So I resolved the infinite loop from happening when adding credit card info, but still has infinite loop when submitting with no credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

componentDidUpdate shouldn't replace componentWillRecieveProps for this reason. The replacement React gave us was getDerivedStateFromProps which you can read about here https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-react-16-3-component-life-cycle-23129bc7a705. However, getDerivedStateFromProps is a static function so you'll have to replace all the setState lines in _validate and return an object instead.

Comment: I remember reading about `getDerivedStateFromProps` but because it is a `static` function, I don't quite remember how I got around to using CDU instead. The only `setState()` lines in `_validate()` function is what's inside the `if` conditional, which seems to exist to update state depending on whether `isValid` is true or not. What kind of object would replace `setState` to serve the same purpose of updating state?

Comment: It's just an object with all the same fields as state, because React will merge that in similar to `setState`. So you would still use `validationErrors` and `displayErrors`, and just change `this.setState({ validationErrors, displayErrors: true });` to `return { validationErrors, displayErrors: true };`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you work with prevState and hooks.

Working sample [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-galileo-1w635)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ZeroToTen = ({ value }) => {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(0);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const validate = value => {
    var result = value >= 0 && value <= 10;
    setIsValid(result);
    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyValue(prevState => (validate(value) ? value : prevState));
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <span>{myValue}</span>
      <p>
        {isValid
          ? `${value} Is Valid`
          : `${value} is Invalid, last good value is ${myValue}`}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button value={value} onClick={e => setValue(prevState => prevState - 1)}>
        Decrement
      </button>
      <button value={value} onClick={e => setValue(prevState => prevState + 1)}>
        Increment
      </button>

      <p>Current Value: {value}</p>

      <ZeroToTen value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

We have two components, one to increase/decrease a number and the other one to hold a number between 0 and 10.

The first component is using prevState to increment the value like this:

```
onClick={e => setValue(prevState => prevState - 1)}
```

It can increment/decrement as much as you want.

The second component is receiving its input from the first component, but it will validate the value every time it is updated and will allow values between 0 and 10.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMyValue(prevState => (validate(value) ? value : prevState));
  }, [value]);
```

In this case I'm using two hooks to trigger the validation every time 'value' is updated.

If you are not familiar with hooks yet, this may be confusing, but the main idea is that with hooks you need to focus on a single property/state to validate changes.